# Create a custom block in web.config for web.config with a random number of elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I need to create a custom block in web config as follows:

```
<MySettings>
    <add name="name1" value="value1" />
    <add name="name2" value="value2" />
    <add name="name3" value="value3" />
    ...
</MySettings>
```

Ad i understand, i should derive my custom settings class from ConfigurationSection, but i don't know how to make it scalable. I need to add a lot of items to that block, and use it as a key-value pair.

I also understand that it's possible to do it all through  section, but i need to create a custom one, since key and value fields might not be enough for me and i will need to extend them.

Thank you very much for assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a structure of add/clear/remove child elements the type matching the `MySettings` element needs to derive from [ConfigurationElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what i needed!
i will post a full version of solution for further usage of community!