# Unable to read in my custom .config section

Tags: .net, configuration, configurationelement

NOTE: this is very very similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772474/create-a-custom-block-in-web-config-for-web-config-with-a-random-number-of-elemen), but I need some more help.

i'm trying to make the following section in my .config file, but i get an exception when trying to *access* this section.

#### .config file

```
<configSections>
    <section name="foos" type="Ackbar.Mvc.Models.Foo.FooCollection, Ackbar.Mvc" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<foos>
    <add name="aaa" something="zzz"/>
    <add name="bbb" something="yyy"/>
    <add name="ccc" something="xxx"/>
</foos>
```

Ok, so this means i need to make *two* classes

#### classes

```
public class FooCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    ... with my custom overrides, etc. ...
}
```

and

```
public class FooElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { .. }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Something ", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Something { .. }

    [ConfigurationProperty("IsDefault ", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = false)]
    public bool IsDefault { .. }
}
```

Kewl. Now, when i do the following ....

`var whatever = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("foos")` is throws the following exception :-

> An error occurred creating the
> configuration section handler for
> foos: Type
> 'Ackbar.Mvc.Models.Foos.FooCollection'
> does not inherit from
> 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'.

Can someone please help me? I don't want to wrap the collection INSIDE a parent section.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *must* implement an `IConfigurationSectionHandler`. No way around that.

However, you may be able to let your `FooCollection` implement that interface as well.

The [IsDefaultCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationpropertyattribute.isdefaultcollection.aspx) attribute property may also come in handy.

Comment: Got it :) _finally- took me ages. i'll post some code in my opening post to help others. Cheers mate!

Comment: `IConfigurationSectionHandler` has been deprecated since .NET 1.1. Use the `ConfigurationSection` class instead.

Comment: @RoastBeast You should put that an answer, trying to work out what `object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)` expects is a waste of time when you can just change the inherited type.

Answer (score 1):

`FooCollection` is not a section, so you should have it extend `ConfigurationSection`.

Though, you'll still need to create the `ConfigurationElementCollection` as the backing collection, you just need to wire it up differently. I would name things a bit differently with `FooSection` for the section itself.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="foos" type="Ackbar.Mvc.Models.Foo.FooSection, Ackbar.Mvc" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>

<foos>
    <add name="aaa" something="zzz"/>
    <add name="bbb" something="yyy"/>
    <add name="ccc" something="xxx"/>
</foos>
```

And the section:

```
public class FooSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection=true)]
    public FooCollection Foos => (FooCollection)this[""];

    // optionally add convenience accessors to the `Foos` collection
}
```